# How to check when a key is pressed in Java

Tags: java

I want to know how to have java check if a key is pressed, for example when someone presses the "UP" key on their keyboard.

Comment: Look up key listeners.

Comment: hexafraction its not a error I just want to know how to do it XD

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: Try *Is Stackoverflow.com Google?* in Google search and see what you get.

Comment: The question is simply unanswerable without further context.  Java determines a keystroke event based on the implementation of the native message queue set up the installed `java.awt.Toolkit`, this gets placed into the event queue and is then managed by the Event Dispatching Thread, passed to each component that has registered interest in the been notified of some kind of key events.  This is further filtered by component and is sent to any registered `KeyListener`s.  This will only occur if the component is focusable and has focus of course.  Key bindings will also be triggered as required...

Comment: OK, I didn't KNOW there was a KeyListener I'M NEW TO JAVA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a KeyListener!!!

Swing was designed to be used with [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: Key bindings and Key listeners are different tools. This answer feels more like a comment reply (to comments) than an answer.

Comment: @user2864740, `Key bindings and Key listeners are different tools.` Exactly! Since, a KeyListener was mentioned twice in the comments, I was trying to stress that a KeyListner should NOT be used. I then proceeded to suggest that using `Key Bindings` is the preferred approach when using Swing, since all Swing components use `Key Binding` to handle an event like "pressing the UP key".